# Is it possible to estimate real world objects relative height if I only have fundamental matrix with a uncalibrated camera

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I already get the epipolar lines and fundamental matrix from images taken by uncalibrated camera.
Is it possible to know 2 real world objects relative height?
I am thinking can it calculate by triangle similarity, but not sure is it ok.

For example I have images like below, is it possible to know the tree is x% height than the house?

[image]

Comment: You might have better luck finding an answer to this question on a different Stack Exchange site. I'm not entirely sure, but I'm not entirely sure which. [Computer Science SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com) might be a good choice.

Comment: Have you tried writing any code so far? Usually you'll get a better response if you can show what you've already tried and where you're stuck (but if you're truly stuck at the very start, i guess there isn't much else you can do).

Comment: @jirassimok this question is about computer vision and includes the 'python' tag. More info would be helpful but it doesn't really seem off-topic.

Comment: @Z4-tier I agree, so I didn't flag it as off-topic. I made the suggestion because the question looks to be rather closer to the theoretical/mathematical side of CS than this site's regular fare, and I thought another site might be more helpful.